# Remove SwiftUI NavigationLink arrow when in a List

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I currently have a view like this:

[image: current view setup with button]

The blue icon is currently a `Button` which is set to show a sheet. I want to change this sheet to a completely separate view, so I understand I will need to change the `Button` to a `NavigationLink`

The code for this is:

```
List {
    Section {
        HStack {
            TextField("Name", text: $item.name)
            Button(action: {
                isPresentingScanner = true
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "barcode.viewfinder")
            })
        }
    } header: {
        Text("Name")
    } footer: {
        Text("Click the icon to scan a product barcode")
    }
}
```

However when I change this to a `NavigationView`, the formatting gets messed up. The arrow icon appears (which I do not want) and the icon gets moved to a more central position.

[image: view setup with navigationview]

The code for this is:

```
List {
        Section {
            HStack {
                TextField("Name", text: $item.name)
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Example View")) {
                    Image(systemName: "barcode.viewfinder")
                }
            }
        } header: {
            Text("Name")
        } footer: {
            Text("Click the icon to scan a product barcode")
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve the look of the first picture example, but the functionality of a NavigationView (i.e. being able to push to a new view) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want the arrow, why do you need `NavigationLink` in the first place?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it's the only way I can push to a new view, whilst still having all the functionality of the navigation stack (e.g. nav bar titles, back buttons etc..)

Comment: See `navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:)`.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed! If you post this answer I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: No, that's not necessary.  Go ahead and have fun with `navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:)`.